# AJAX and PHP crash server

Tags: php, ajax, crash, server

I have a simple page with a DB table that is updated every second using a AJAX POST request to a PHP page.
After 40/50 minutes the server crashes and it is out of service for 1 hour.
Is it a known issue?

```
function runAjax(){
    var filename = "readDB.php";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",   
        url: filename,   
        data: abc_params,
        success: function(msg){   
             processResponse(msg);
        }
    });   
}
function processResponse(txt){  
    dosomething(txt);
    setTimeout("runAjax()",1000);
}
setTimeout("runAjax()",1000);
```

readDB.php simply returns a string with all fields of 1 row of 1 table of the DB

UPDATE:
I tried also with a "readDB.php" page like this:

```
<?echo "OK";?>
```

After 2 hours the site php pages give error 500 but only after 1 minute the site works correctly again.

Comment: please edit your question to include the ajax call and the relevant php code. You can also check the php logs to see more information about what causes the crash.

Comment: Please add php code here, crash server in terms of what ?

Comment: Check if you are closing connection to the database after writing to db. Maybe the number of active connections to your db is causing this. Try increasing the max allowed number of connection to database and check if that is the issue.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I do not write to db, only read. The active connection could cause the issue?

Comment: server crashes I mean php pages give: HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
C:\PHP\php-cgi.exe - The FastCGI process exceeded configured request timeout

Answer (score 0):

Here may be problem with mysql connection limit, So please follow like :

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

using "mysql_close" it will terminate connection